# WPF form XAML : How to correctly position these controls (and get the button to behave normally when clicked)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So, I am new to WPF. Actually, this is my first WPF project. I come from a unix desktop (and Web) programming background, so I'm not new to programming or mark up languages.

**Q1:** First, My application is a simple dialog that cannot be min/maximized or resized (for simplicity), so I don't mind fixing (ie. hardcoding) my layout.

Using HTML to explain, this is what I want my "form" to look like:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span>This is my Left Adjusted Title</span>
        <span>Some Right Adjusted Stuff</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
             <div>This is the parent container</div>
             <div>
                  <div>Title for option 1</div>
                  <div>
                       Radio Button for option 1
                  </div>

                  <div>Title for option 2</div>
                  <div>
                       Radio Buttons for option 2
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div>
             <span>Right Floated Button</span>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div>
            <div>These are the Results</div>
            <textarea>
                Vertically scrollable text here (nice if can be color formatted with underlines etc) ...
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div><a href='http://www.google.com'>Click here</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This, on the other hand, is my XAML (which I have kludged together from the Visual Designer):

```
<Window x:Name="wndMain" x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ews="clr-namespace:ExtraWindowStyles"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        ews:ExtraWindowStyles.CanMinimize="false" 
        ews:ExtraWindowStyles.CanMaximize="false"         
        Title="Hello World" Height="501.492" Width="842.285">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Input Parameters" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="173" Margin="10,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="801" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,96,0">
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold">First Group</Label>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt11">Option 1 - 1</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt12">Option 1 - 2</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt13">Option 1 - 3</RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Second Group"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt21" Content="Option 2 - 1"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt22" Content="Option 2 - 2"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt23" Content="Option 2 - 3"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </GroupBox>
        <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="17,203,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="794"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSubmit" Content="Explore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="632,203,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" Click="btnSubmit_Click"  />
        <Label Content="Results:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="10,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161"/>
        <Label Content="My App" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="696,439,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" FontSize="9"/>
        <TextBlock>           
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                Click Here
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="162" Margin="17,270,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="794"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblResult" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="157" Margin="17,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="794"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do I fix this XAML so it is rendered the way I showed in the HTML snippet?

**Q2:** Why does the WPF rendered button not behave like a button?. This is really wierd, it does not depress when clicked, how do I get the 'normal' button click behaviour ?

Comment: None of your controls are actually using the `Grid` that they are part of, they are all positioned statically.  The grid should have Column and Row Definitions, and each control should have a Grid.Column and Grid.Row attributes.  You may need to nest some internal Grids or stack panels to get the exact layout you want.

Comment: Please create a separate SO question for each separate issue you are facing.

Comment: @BradleyUffner has provided what you need.  I can show you further, but I'm not sure what's up with the `TextBlock` containing the "Click Here" `Hyperlink` that covers everything else in the window.  What's that actually supposed to look like?

Comment: Also keep in mine that you will get along with WPF *much* better if you use the MVVM pattern.  Things just fall in to place better, even though it can be a bit of a mind flip if you aren't used to it.  This means that repeating items, like your radio buttons, shouldn't be hard coded as 3 separate items, but instead should be a single repeater type control bound to a list on the View Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've (mostly) updated your XAML, attached below, to get you started in the right direction.  Of note, pay attention, as Bradley Uffner mentioned, to how elements are arranged within the `Grid` via `RowDefinitions` and the `Grid.Row` attached property.

Further, as you progress in WPF, look into MVVM pattern, as it creates much cleaner and more logic code, being much easier to maintain.  To this end, you'll want to start familiarizing yourself on the `Binding` expressions in WPF, such as can be found at [A Data Binding Primer](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/10/02/a-data-binding-primer.aspx).

I've left most of your static `Height` definitions in place, but you can also allow these controls to fit dynamically via any combination of `Height` on `RowDefinition`, `Width` on `ColumnDefinition`, and the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` of the controls themselves.

```
<Window x:Name="wndMain" x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfControlPositioning"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Title="Hello World" Height="501.492" Width="842.285"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Input Parameters" Height="173" Margin="10">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold">First Group</Label>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt11">Option 1 - 1</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt12">Option 1 - 2</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt13">Option 1 - 3</RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Second Group"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt21" Content="Option 2 - 1"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt22" Content="Option 2 - 2"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt23" Content="Option 2 - 3"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>

        <Separator Grid.Row="1" Height="3" Margin="10,0"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="2" x:Name="btnSubmit" Content="Explore" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="34" Margin="10" Width="179" Click="btnExplore_Click"  />

        <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Results:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0"/>

        <!-- I don't know what to make of this, so I've left it commented out.
                <TextBlock>
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                        Click Here
                    </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
                -->

        <!-- Note that I've substituted a ReadOnly TextBox in place of the Rectangle + Label here.  The TextBox supplies
                     the bordered look of the rectangle, but has the different behavior of allowing text selection from within
                     the control, such as for copying your Results to paste elsewhere. -->
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" x:Name="lblResult" Margin="10,0" IsReadOnly="True" Background="#FFF4F4F5" BorderBrush="Black"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="5" Content="My App" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="23" Margin="0" FontSize="9"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to point out that, since you were arranging everything via `Margin` and had some odd sizes and layouts of some elements (i.e., the "Click Here" link) that the reason your `Button` didn't behave as expected is because it had other controls overlaying the top of it.

Comment: +1 Fantastic!, Thanks!. Somehow, I can now make the mental link between XAML and HTML.  The "Click here" portion of the snippet is a red herring, I was just experimenting with rendering different controls in XAML. 

That's the layout sorted out then. Last but not the least, do you know why the button is not behaving like a normal button?. Why is it not getting 'depressed' when it is clicked, and how do I fix that?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Added an edit.  I had that in mind when I originally went to update the layout, but had forgotten to include that note by the time I posted my answer.

Comment: I just tested the XAML you provided, however the buttons behaviour remains unchanged. By "normal", I mean that I want (expect) the button to *visually* look depressed (I think a shadow effect is added), when the button is clicked,so that it **looks like** the button is depressed, when it is clicked. This is helpful for visually impaired users, who may otherwise not realize that the button click has occurred when they press the mouse over the button.

In WinForms, this was the default behaviour of buttons, I guess this has changed in WPF?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli This is the default behavior in WPF.  I believe it's to be more inline with the Metro/flat/simple look more common now, and in use across multiple devices.  To change that behavior, you'd have to add a style based on triggers, similar to here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10840170/1223642